# How to add send Digital Catalogues(example shown in the image below) via Whatsapp Business API?

Tags: whatsapp, facebook-business-sdk

I'm trying to build a Food Order taking bot in WhatsApp. However I do not see an option to create a message template for publishing food menus as shown in the image below.

[image]